# Where is RestClient.send defined?

Tags: ruby, rest, client

I have trying to understand where RestClient.send is defined to no avail :-(

Let me explain to you what I mean:

I have been checking out iqengines.com ruby api gem and they use RestClient.send to call out their api:

https://github.com/iqengines/ruby-iqengines/blob/master/lib/iqengines.rb

Now they use RestClient gem and this call to send out the http request:
response = RestClient.send(method, url, fields)

I looked inside rest_client gem https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client and I can not 
undestand where rest-client gem defines RestClient.send(...) method!!

Any help would be creatly appreciated!!

Comment: `send` is defined in Ruby's `Object` class. Ie `"foo".send(:reverse) #=> "oof"`

Comment: @ thanks inject! Oh, yes, it all about metaprogramming!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`send` method is a part of Ruby. see here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send

Comment: Thanks akonsu about that pointer. It slipped my mind!. Metapragramming can be tricky